# setTimeout(fn(), delay) doesnt delay as expected

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I  must be missing something quite obvious here because something rather strange is happening

I have a bit of js code that goes pretty much like this

```
setTimeout(myFn(), 20000);
```

If I m correct when I hit that line, after 20 seconds `myFn` should run right?

in my case myFn is an ajax call and it happens quite fast ( not at 20seconds and I just dont understand why. Any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Someone had the same mistake last night. Is this the new popular JavScript mistake to make?

Comment: When I first moved out of the service side code into the client side it was my first mistake...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

setTimeout(myFn,20000);

When you say setTimeout(myFn(),20000) your telling it to evaluate myFn() and call the return value after 20 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that myFn() is a function call not function pointer.
You need to do:

```
 setTimeout(myFn, 20000);
```

Otherwise the myFn will be run before the timer is set.

Answer (score 2):

No, the correct line would be `setTimeout(myFn, 20000);`

In yours, you're actually calling the `myFn` without delay, on the same line, and its result is scheduled to run after 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `()`. If you put them, the function is called directly. Without them, it passed the function as argument.